# python and package installment while application is installed

Tags: python, windows

I have done some image processing works using python 3.5, opencv, scikit modules etc for an unreal engine game application.

I have manually installed python and other modules using pip in my windows system.

Now when a user installs the application, i want python and those modules to be installed auto with the application's installment.

I saw pyinstaller which turns py file to application file but unfortunately could not understand how to work it of what i want.

Thank you for any piece of advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let me say `Python packaging` has improved a lot over the years, but is still considered very hard compared to other languages like e.g. `golang`.

Generally, I see two ways how to bring your applications to your user.

Either make a `Python package` or create an installable package for an operation system.

A `Python package` means, you could upload it somewhere (e.g. PyPi) and your users could `pip install your_package`. This involves a lot of work. A good starting point would be:
https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/

The second option is to create an `installer` or e.g. Windows.

There are several tools out there, like the mentioned `pyinstaller`, more on this page: https://docs.python-guide.org/shipping/freezing/

Also, there is a new option called PyOxidizer ( https://pyoxidizer.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html ).

At work we used `cx_Freeze` - which worked ok.

Unfortunately, there is no easy way. Have a look at several options, and then decide for one.

Comment: Thank you so very much! I would like to have a look into the second option and play around the options.